# Understanding authentication providers in Spring security

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I am trying to understand authentication providers in Spring (3.1) and I have a question to what is really happening here. I know that I use the namespace that gives easier access to functionality and configuration in the security module.

When I have the following tags I get a provider manager which have a list of authentication providers. Now as I look at the `AuthenticationProvider` interface I wonder what kind of providers I get? Am I right that I get a `DaoAuthenticationProvider`? Do I get other providers and how is it able to find out which providers to register (if this is how it is done)?

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"  />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right you are going to get a `DaoAuthenticationProvider` with the above config. The [documentation for `<authentication-provider>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-authentication-provider) clearly states:

> Unless used with a `ref` attribute, this element is shorthand for configuring a `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.

The `<authentication-provider>` tag is parsed by `AuthenticationProviderBeanDefinitionParser` which invariably [registers a `DaoAuthenticationProvider`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/authentication/AuthenticationProviderBeanDefinitionParser.java#L24) injected with the specified `UserDetailsService` and other collaborators (passwordEncoder, saltSource, etc.).

Comment: Ah, sweet. Didn't find documentation for the namespace tags. Thank you!